# footnote numbering

Tags: tables, tabulary

Whatever I do the footnote starts with the number 5. How can I change that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{footnote}{1}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLL} \hline
\textbf{x} & x & \textbf{x} & \textbf{x}\\ \hline 
x & x & x\footnote{y} & x\\
x\footnote{y} & x & x\footnote{y} & x\\\hline
\end{tabulary} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see 5,6 and 7 in your MWE...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code down to the bare minimum that still replicates the issue you've reported.

Comment: For some reason, the `tabulary` environment currently adds `3` to the footnote counter. As you're setting `\setcounter{footnote}{1}` manually (the counter's initial value is `0`, by the way), the first footnote in the `tabulary` environment has the number `5`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you've discovered appears to be limited to the `tabulary` environment. For some reason, `3` is being added to the `footnote` counter when a `tabulary` environment is initiated. (This must surely be unintended. The version of the `tabulary` package is `2014/06/11 v0.10`.)

Here's a quick fix you may apply until an updated version of the `tabulary` package is distributed: Add the following code to the preamble.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabulary}{\addtocounter{footnote}{-3}}
```